# Download file without target_blank?

Tags: jquery

So I have a button which, when clicked, downloads a file to the users computer. The image thats downloaded is retrieved through an API. I'm not sure if its possible but is there a way to download the file without opening it in a new tab with target_blank? Or not opening any window/tab for that matter.

Thanks!! Sorry! I'm really new to jquery/javascript.

Comment: Why don't you solve this server side? I guess all you need is a Content-Disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

you can have hidden iframe in your page and redirect the download there.